# Zend Studio keeps loading with-in a project folder. How do I get it to load so my top level elements are all my projects?

Tags: zend-studio

Yes I set "top level elements" to "projects"

Here is how it looks when I load my zend studio. [image]

I want it to load so that all my projects are there instead of having to press that up button 20 times...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the file below to edit in your favorite text editor:
workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench\workbench.xml

In my case:
C:\Users\juliano\Zend\workspaces\DefaultWorkspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench

And find the line:

```
<input factoryID="org.eclipse.ui.internal.model.ResourceFactory" path="/xxx" type="4"/>
```

In my case it was:

```
<input factoryID="org.eclipse.ui.internal.model.ResourceFactory" path="/Electrolux" type="4"/>
```

and replace it by

```
<input factoryID="org.eclipse.ui.internal.model.ResourceFactory" path="/" type="8"/>
```

And again have peace!

Comment: you my friend are a god send. Thank you :)

Comment: When you open in new window a project folder, have this behavior if you close the old window. Therefore, always close the window open last, first ok?